# How Call remote web service using SOAP ENV and catch Soap Exception

Tags: c#, webclient, soapexception

I am accessing a web service (remote) using C#'s WebClient.UploadString method and I am passing the SOAPEnv with the required credentials and data.

It works fine, but, I am not able to catch the SoapException which is returned by the remote web service. I read the WebClient.UploadString method and it returns WebException or the generic exception.

I am just wondering how to call the web service using the SoapEnv and also catch the SOAPException. The reason for using the WebClient method is to pass SoapEnv because the web service requires WS-Security Authentication.

Regards,
Jaggy

Answer (score 0):

Try to catch soap exception and use soap faults accordingly
also try to work with request/response methods so that you can get raw response.

```
try
{
  //Do calling web service
}
catch (SoapException soapEx)
{
  // Get soap exception here
   //Try to read soap faults here
}
catch(WebException wex)
{
  //Read network errors here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use Add Service Reference to your project and create a WCF client proxy?
It seems to working fine with all kind of services.

At least at my scenarios.